# How to adjust AutoDateFormatter according to xline dates?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

So, i set up major `AutoDateLocator()` so `matplotlib` can adjust graph properly. But and a `AutoDateFormatter()` method seems to fail to understand how [format dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fF1K.png) in `xaxis` correctly. All data a formatted by `"%Y-%m-%d %M:%H"` in pandas DataFrame. So, for example, if overall time is under 24 hours, a expect to see only `%M:%H"` format. If we talking about mouths, it's better be `%d:%m:%Y"` and so on [but not this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1BhC.png).

Here's the Locator and Formatter code:

```
locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(locator))
```

.xlsx data formatting and [a table itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnK0v.png):

```
        data = pd.read_excel(('Overall_calc.xlsx'), sheet_name='Combine_PythonInput', header=0, skiprows=2)
    data["start"] = pd.to_datetime(data["start_H"].astype(str).str.pad(2, fillchar="0") +
                                   data["start_M"].astype(str).str.pad(2, fillchar="0"),
                                   format="%H%M")
    data["end"] = pd.to_datetime(data["end_H"].astype(str).str.pad(2, fillchar="0") +
                                 data["end_M"].astype(str).str.pad(2, fillchar="0"),
                                 format="%H%M")

    data["duration_H"] = pd.to_timedelta(data["duration_H"], unit='hour')
    data["duration_M"] = pd.to_timedelta(data["duration_M"], unit='min')
    data["duration"] = pd.to_timedelta(data["duration_M"] + data["duration_H"])
    data.drop(["start_H","start_M","end_H","end_M",'duration_H', 'duration_M'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

and i think [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4808) may do smth in common

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: first row didn't tabulate correctly, i dunno why, although this is not the case

Answer (score 0):

Ok, iam sorry if i didn't express myself correctly, but i figure out how to do what need. It's just a simple method from dates.py:

```
    formatter.scaled[1] = "%d.%m.%y"
    formatter.scaled[1 / 24] = '%d.%m - %H:%M'
    formatter.scaled[1 / 1440] = '%d.%m - %H:%M'
    formatter.scaled[1 / 86400] = '%d.%m - %H:%M:%S'
```

After that, autoformatter will show dates as you expected.